# Will flattening a large array constant reduce the number of L1 cache misses?

Tags: rust, constants, cpu-cache

I have a Rust program which uses a few literal constants. The constants are arrays of type `[u128; 8]` - `[u128; 10]` and one two-dimensional array of size `[[[u128; 8]; 8]; 100]`; this array is 100KB.

Analyzing with KCachegrind tells me that reading from this array is responsible for about 70% of L1-Read-Misses, which essentially slows my program down.

Would the cache misses be reduced if the array was flattened? That is, instead of indexing with `arr[x][y][z]`, I would index with `arr[64 * x + 8 * y + z]`

If flattening the array does actually reduce the cache misses, why doesn't the compiler flatten the array for me and explicitly change the indexing?

If it doesn't, how would I go about reducing the cache misses?

Comment: A flattened array will have identical memory layout, so it shouldn't make any difference for the generated code. Apart from that, it's next to impossible to comment further – the cache misses depend on the entirety of your program, your architecture and your platform.

Comment: Random access of a 100kB block of data is likely to result in a lot of cache misses. Try to rewrite your algorithm so that it accesses the data sequentially. It's difficult to offer more detailed suggestions without seeing your code. Consider creating a [mcve].